# How to know if a block is finalized

Tags: finalization

I use Subxt for parsing blocks but am only interested in finalized blocks.
I know that Subxt provides a WebSocket-based subscription for finalized blocks, but WebSockets are unavailable to me.

Is there any API call, storage query, or data in a block header providing this information?

Comment: unless this use websockets, i think it might be what you want https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/rpc/struct.Rpc.html#method.subscribe_finalized_block_headers